# Replace LED with resistor in Christmas light string

Tags: led, resistors

A rodent chewed up an LED socket on a 100 light, warm white 3.2 V light string. I want to replace the socket with a resistor to keep the string within its voltage and current parameters. What would be the correct resistance and wattage of the resistor? The resistor would be encased in marine shrink tubing and secured with a wired support.

Comment: You don't need to replace it with anything as long as the rest are working.

Comment: Yes, concur @EugeneSh. Just short out that section, if that is in series with many other LEDs. First, that rat has bad Christmas spirit! Let's give it a good name, Grinch the Rat.

Comment: @jay Not sure the shorting would be a good idea, this is why I added "as long as the rest are working". We don't know what kind of topology it is

Comment: @EugeneSh. absolutely, we gotta fix this lights before the Christmas Eve.

Comment: The best component to use would be a blue or white LED.

Comment: An led is a good idea. I just have to insure the led leads are well supported and won't eventually crack due to wind movement. I realize the change in wattage is not that great  without one led but I am not sure how to calculate the change given the resistors, diodes or other components in the light string.

Comment: "I want to replace the socket with a resistor to keep the string within its voltage and current parameters. What would be the correct resistance and wattage of the resistor?" This is complete nonsense, similar to "how long is a rope?". You cannot keep anything within it's parameters if you don't know them. You need to know how the LEDs are connected, how many there are, what supply voltage you have, what forward voltage the LEDs have and so on.